# Asp.net core 2 - Files are not published

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, csproj

**EDIT**

For info, I'm developping on macOS using VS Code

I'm trying to include files in my publish process ( Currently `cshtml`that represents my email templates ).

I follow this [thread](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/795) on github but seems that their solutions don't work for me.

Here my csproj to add an unique `cshtml` file :

```
  <Target Name="PrepublishScript" BeforeTargets="PrepareForPublish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmailFile Include="$(ProjectDir)/EmailTemplates/OrderCompleteEmail.cshtml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(EmailFile)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" SkipUnchangedFiles="false" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: look for msbuild info. EmailFile is not a default variable/property in msbuild. Check this question links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452962/list-of-msbuild-built-in-variables

Comment: Have you tried to set the file to copy to the output folder? Right click -> Properties -> Build Action = None, Copy To Output Directory = Copy If Newer. When I try this with a text file it is published along with everything else

Comment: why don't use [CopyToPublishDirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42713770/2833802) property?

Comment: @Set I already tried CopyToPublishDirectory without sucess.

Comment: @bradbury ok. Thinking that we can create nodes ^^'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your solution was almost correct, you have to use `AfterTargets="Publish"`:

```
<Target Name="CopyCustomContentOnPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmailFile Include="EmailTemplates/OrderCompleteEmail.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(EmailFile)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)" />
</Target>
```

You can also copy all your email templates in a single Target to the same folder like:

```
  <Target Name="CopyCustomContentOnPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmailTemplates Include="EmailTemplates\*.cshtml" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(EmailTemplates)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)%(EmailTemplates.RelativeDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Yes I did it like that some times ago ^^

Comment: Nice, solution, though be careful, there is a strange discrapancy between dotnet publish and VS 2017 (15.8.4) Publish - VS won't work with `AfterTargets="AfterPublish"` but will with `AfterTargets="Publish"`. The later works with both - VS and dotnet publish.

Comment: Thank you for you comment @theberserker, I updated my answer based on it.

Comment: Apparently you can also use globs with the `<EmailFile Include="Folder/**" />` approach