# views folder is missing in asp.net core 2.0 after publish

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on asp.net core 2.0 web application and I am publishing code to local folder using visual studio 2017 but I see views folder is not published. I see a dll named WebApplication1.PrecompiledViews.dll. Where are views folder gone. How can I get views folders?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Views are always compiled in ASP.NET Core. You never get a `Views` folder when you publish an ASP.NET Core app.

Comment: that is not really true, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46255990/publish-the-views-with-asp-net-core