# ASP.NET Core MVC application weird behavior on publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So here is my ASP.NET Core MVC project, which is working fine locally but not when I am trying to publish my target project `TSEventApp.Web` to a target folder:

[image]

The project is getting published successfully but it just publishes weird folders with just .dll files instead of folders like views, bin, etc. Can anyone just please guide me through what exactly am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is it visual studio 22?

Comment: No Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61359543/9695286

Answer (score 2):

According to your publish settings, I found you used the Framework-dependent, it you use this format, it will not generate the related runtime dll and it will complie all the view or else inside the one dll.

If you choose self-contained, it will genreate the runtime related dll inside the folder .

Comment: Okay! So you are saying that I should Self-contained?

Comment: Could you please tell me why you need these folders? Asp.net core will compile all the files into the dll instead of sperate them. So this dll will also work well when you host it inside IIS or else.